# Mod Rewrite General Rule for ALL Pagination?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, pagination

Could something like this be done? No matter what page or directory `page=$1` appears under it'll be rewritten/redirected to `/$1`

For example:

**file.php/1** would be **file.php?page=1**

**dir/file/2** would be **dir/file?page=2**

**dir/file.php?name=something/3** would be **dir/file.php?name=something&page=3**

Here's what I have so far:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s.+\.php\sHTTP/.+
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&page=([0-9-]+)/?$ 
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ $1/%2 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php/$2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To cover the URI paths that end with **/123** we can use this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/([0-9]+)$ /$1?page=$2 [QSA,L,R]
```

So:

- **file.php/1** would be **file.php?page=1**
- **dir/file/2** would be **dir/file?page=2**
- Note that this will also cover: **dir/file/3?foo=bar** would be **dir/file?page=3&foo=bar**

To cover the **/123** that gets appended *at the end of the actual query string*, we can use this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (.*)/([0-9]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1?%1&page=%2 [L]
```

So:

- **dir/file.php?name=something/3** would be **dir/file.php?name=something&page=3**